# HREF is referencing itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, href

I am building an App is VS Pro 2013 using .NET4.5 C#/ASP.NET. I am also using Bootstrap.min.js and JQuery 2.1.4.in.js.

I have created a folder structure for a certain set of web pages. From the root directory it looks like this:

***Root Dir/Folder/Folder/Folder/Default.aspx***

I also have a navbar on the page which has drop downs. In the drop downs I have added my HREF's to other pages in and around my folder structure for the web pages.

I have two links in the drop down menu that reference web pages, as you would expect using HREF.

The code for the navbar is as folows:

```
<li class="dropdown"  >
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer">Sites
                               <b class="caret"></b> 
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">View Site Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">View Site Reports</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Set/Edit Site Targets</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="~/EMS/Sites/EditSite/Default.aspx">Edit Site Details</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/EMS/Sites/Addsite/Default.aspx">Add Another Site</a></li>                               
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

There are only two active links, I took the others out as they were also doing the same thing.

When I run the application, what I see when I hover over the link on the drop down is ***localhost:port#/EMS/Sites/AddSite/~EMS/Sites/Addsite/Default.aspx*** when it should in fact be ***localhost:port#/EMS/Sites/AddSite/Default.aspx***

Its as if it has taken the present location of the aspx file and then added the HREF link to the end of it. As this location doesn't exist, it 404's.

I have tried changing the path from relative to absolute and mixing up things, but it is not a happy bunny.

I have also tried in web.config and routeconfig.cs...

Any ideas anyone, I have never come across this before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any link that starts with anything other than a protocol (e.g., `http://`) or a `/` is going to be seen as a relative link, i.e., relative to the current page. If you want your links to be relative to the site root, use `/~/...`.

That said, based on your description of what you're trying to do, I'm not sure why you used `~` at all; that should probably be `#`.

Comment: Once I read your comment I understood what I was doing wrong. I changed the path to "../EditSite/Default.aspx". Thanks for the info...

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ed Cottrell for sending me down the right path, so to speak.

Due to the amount of nesting I had in my folders, I could not use relative paths, with that much nesting. As the application may move around and it is still in pre prod, I didn't want to change all of the HREFs when it goes to prod or is moved, hence the folders. So I moved all of my content up a level rather than nesting the folders the webpages were in, so the web pages are all in their own folder. This means that each page has its own folder, meaning I don't have to change the internal HREF for this part of the application, ever.

This allowed me to use '../Folder/'. I also set my default page in IIS to default.aspx, so I only have to reference the folder the page is in.

Where I need to step out of this part of the application, I will have  to provide a full reference with protocol (http://somesite/someotherfolder etc).

I think that's right...